# scp and rsync to transfer data from Linux to Android

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'd like to be able to push PDF files onto a phone/tablet with a Bash script. Is it possible to transfer data using scp (or even rsync) from a Linux computer to an Android phone over wireless?

Could I even run Unison on the phone?

And is it possible to run Bash (or only POSIX Shell) scripts on the phone remotely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many things are possible. Installing an SSH Server app (e.g. [SSHelper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arachnoid.sshelper) or [DigiSSHD / SSH Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.digimead.digi.ctrl.sshd)) would give you the possibility to login via ssh, or remote-copy via scp.

[Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside) (available only for Android 4.4 and earlier, according to the app description) gives you a quite complete package, even including the famous Midnight Commander, and a lot more useful tools:

> javac, java, dx, proguard, aapt, apkbuilder, signer, ssh, **sshd**, telnetd, **bash** 4.2, busybox 1.19.2, vim 7.3, nano 2.2.6, midnight commander 4.8, htop 1.0, TMUX 1.5, **rsync** 3.0.8, git 1.7.8, BitchX 1.1 and a nice terminal emulator are all available.

(emphasis are introduced by me to pick the items your question was for)

So except for Unison, the latter package should cover your needs :)

Comment: Vim, htop and git are also very nice. Thanks!

Comment: Yepp, exactly! Side-effect is: you get a complete development environment on your Android :) But it will make up a couple of MB, naturally...

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny thanks! Couldn't know that back then :)

Answer (score 0):

For your first question. I use the [OASVN Android client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valleytg.oasvnlite.android) to pull PDF files to my droid from my private Windows based SVN server.  Works Great!!  I used rsync before and would favored the SVN solution over rsync. NetApp's FX File Manager Plus handles the SFTP protocol over wireless and will cost you $2 for a license.

Comment: I took the freedom to add a link to OASVN. Not sure for FX -- do you mean [File Explorer (Plus Add-On)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx.rk)?

Comment: It would be nice to have a concrete example using rsync here (as it is available via Terminal IDE)